# Running a thread for some seconds

Tags: android, multithreading, media-player, decrement

I am using a media player instance to play a music file.I want to play the song for certain time then stop playing.I'm using a thread with counter decrementing but some how tis not workin properly.

Comment: could we see (some of) the code?

Comment: Thanks People.I got it in the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to use handler for that

try this

```
in your onCreate use this 

  //start media player
  mp.start();


  mTimer.sendMessageDelayed(new Message(),5*10000);
```

create a class in you activity class as

```
    private MusicTimer mTimer = new MusicTimer();

    private class MusicTimer extends Handler
    {
       @Override
       handleMessage(Message msg)
       {
           onTimerExpire();
       }  



        public void onTimerExpire()
        {
           //stop player here
        }

}
```

make media player object member variable this will play that for five seconde then stop nthat

Answer (score 3):

this is something you can do.. Play with media player normally and at the same Time initialise a [handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and call its [postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) method with interval you want.. and inside it stop the MEdia player.. Something like this..

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){

//stop playing
}, 400);
```