# How to make Android share button appear on touch?

Tags: android

I am creating a news app which contains a 'share news' button. Currently this button is showing all the time when user reads the news, which makes news reading irritating. Now my question is how can I make that share button show up when user touch on the screen, and will disappear after 2-3 seconds if it is left without touching. It would be nice if I can make a little animation during the button appearing/disappearing (like, show up from bottom and disappear going down). Please help...

Thanks

Comment: Ur question speaks like an unresearched topic by the owner.
And it make me to feel like, you have simply wrote above your work assigned task .

Comment: If you think it is already posted, then please specify the link, because I could not find any suitable answer on Stackoverflow. The other part of your comment is not clear to me, is it illegal to post question about the task which is assigned to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add an on touch event on your view and change visibilty of your button visible when touched after that start an timer using handler for three seconds and set visibility gone there after three seconde for handler code check this answer

[Running a thread for some seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136494/running-a-thread-for-some-seconds/10136652#10136652)